# "invalid literal for int() with base 10:" What does this actually mean?

Tags: python, int

Beginner here! I am writing a simple code to count how many times an item shows up in a list (ex. `count([1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5], 1)` would return 3).

This is what I originally had:

```
def count(sequence, item):
    s = 0
    for i in sequence:
       if int(i) == int(item):
           s += 1
    return s
```

Every time I submitted this code, I got

> "invalid literal for int() with base 10:"

I've since figured out that the correct code is:

```
def count(sequence, item):
    s = 0
    for i in sequence:
       if **i == item**:
           s += 1
    return s
```

However, I'm just curious as to what that error statement means. Why can't I just leave in `int()`?

Comment: What if `sequence` contains objects other than `int`? The error message means that `int` was passed a value that it doesn't know how to convert.

Comment: The first method is fine, are you supplying the right arguments?

Comment: `count([1,3,1,4,1,5],1)` works correctly with your original code. What input did it fail on?

Comment: Please do not duplicate functionality from the standard library. I would recommend you use this: ``[1,3,1,4,1,5].count(1)`` -> ``3``...

Answer (score 18):

The error is "invalid literal for int() with base 10:".  This just means that the argument that you passed to `int` doesn't look like a number.  In other words it's either empty, or has a character in it other than a digit.

This can be reproduced in a python shell.

```
>>> int("x")
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'
```

Comment: @recurvise Your explanation here helped me to understand and resolve a different type problem. Many Many thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this if letters for example, occur in your sequence:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def count_(sequence, item):
    s = 0
    for i in sequence:
        try:
            if int(i) == int(item):
                s = s + 1
        except ValueError:
            print ('Found: ',i, ', i can\'t count that, only numbers', sep='')
    return s

print (count_([1,2,3,'S',4, 4, 1, 1, 'A'], 1))
```