# Take every nth row from a file with groups and n is a given in a column

Tags: python, r, bash, shell, awk

I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850386/select-nth-element-in-data-frame-by-factor) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189882/more-efficient-way-to-take-every-nth-element-in-data-table-by-factors) on how to return every nth row; but my problem is different. A separate column in the file provides specifics about which nth element to return; which are different depending on the group. Here is a sample of the dataset where the `Nth` column provides the rows to return. That is, for `Id` group `a` every 3rd row and for`Id` group `b` every 4th row. The data is quite sizable which with several `Id` groups.

```
Id  TagNo   Nth
a   A-A-3   3
a   A-A-1   3
a   A-A-5   3
a   A-A-2   3
a   AX-45   3
a   AX-33   3
b   B-B-5   4
b   B-B-4   4
b   B-B-3   4
b   BX-B2   4
```

Desired output:

```
Id  TagNo   Nth
 a  A-A-3   3
 a  A-A-2   3
 b  B-B-5   4
```

Thank you for your help.

Edit: Please kindly note that I want to start picking from the `first` and every nth item; that is every 3rd for `a` and 4th for `b`. For group `a` it will be `1st,4th, 7th`... for group b it will be `1st,5th, 9th` rows. The original output has error and an edit has been done. My sincere apologies.

Comment: Why is `AX-45` there?

Comment: Must be a typo, the idea is to return every `3rd` for `a` and every `4th` for `b`. Will do an edit.

Comment: And first? (because you also have `A-A-3` there)

Comment: and `B-B-5` too.

Comment: Yes, I want to start picking from the first and then every `nth`.

Comment: Thank you and an edit is submitted. My sincere apologies; my head might need a recharge ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base `R` solution:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Id), function(x) x[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(x), by = unique(x$Nth)), ]))

    Id TagNo Nth
a.1  a A-A-3   3
a.4  a A-A-2   3
b    b B-B-5   4
```

Comment: This is really a good solution, Could you also try something in data.table

Comment: Sadly, I'm not well versed in data.table. But there are some here (akrun, Sotos and others), who should be able to translate this into data.table.

Comment: I found the `data.table` solution :)

Comment: Thanks @LAP. An elegant `base R` solution.

Answer (score 6):

This `awk` should work:

```
awk '!a[$1]++{print; if(NR>1) n=NR+$3} NR==n{print; n=NR+$3}' file

Id  TagNo   Nth
a   A-A-3   3
a   A-A-2   3
b   B-B-5   4
```

Answer (score 3):

For the `awk` solution,

```
$ cat awk-sc
{
  if(id==$1){
    nth--;
    if(nth==0){print; nth=$3}
  } else {
    id=$1;nth=$3;print
  }
}

$ awk -f awk-sc file
Id  TagNo   Nth
a   A-A-3   3
a   A-A-2   3
b   B-B-5   4
```

Answer (score 2):

Python solution.

```
from __future__ import print_function

with open('file.csv') as f:
    print(*next(f).split())    # header

    lastid = None
    lineno = 0
    for line in f:
        id_, tagno, nth = line.split()

        if lastid != id_:
            lineno = 0

        if lineno % int(nth) == 0:
            print(id_, tagno, nth)

        lastid = id_
        lineno += 1
```

Comment: Thank you but it gave me `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)` error. Will check other solutions first and get back to trace the error.

Comment: @deepseefan Oh, so the file is really not *comma separated*. Edited.

Comment: Had both versions; for the comma separated it gave me a syntax error on line `print(*next(reader))`.

Comment: @deepseefan You should use Python 3 or at very least the `__future__` module.

Comment: Usually I ran the code with `python3`. Now it works; but could you please edit the line `if lineno % (int(nth) - 1) == 0:` to `if lineno % (int(nth)) == 0:` so the output will be as specified in the edit. You are correct it produces the output as specified before edit is made.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base R` solution.
First, the data. I assume you read it in with `dat <- read.csv("file.csv")`.

```
dat <-
structure(list(Id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), TagNo = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 10L), .Label = c("A-A-1", "A-A-2", 
"A-A-3", "A-A-5", "AX-33", "AX-45", "B-B-3", "B-B-4", "B-B-5", 
"BX-B2"), class = "factor"), Nth = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("Id", "TagNo", "Nth"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Now the `R` code.

```
dat2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$Nth), function(x)
            x[c(1 + (1:(nrow(x) %/% x[1, "Nth"]) - 1)*x[1, "Nth"]), ]))
row.names(dat2) <- NULL
dat2
#  Id TagNo Nth
#1  a A-A-3   3
#2  a A-A-2   3
#3  b B-B-5   4
```

Answer (score 2):

**awk** one-liner

```
$ awk 'a!=$1{a=$1; n=$3; k=-1} FNR>1 && ++k%n!=0{next} 1' f1
Id  TagNo   Nth
a   A-A-3   3
a   A-A-2   3
b   B-B-5   4
```

`a!=$1{a=$1; n=$3; k=-1}`: `a` is a variable that keeps track of the first field/column. If `a` is not initialized or the first column is different than the previous one then this will satisfy and it will set `a`, `n` and `k=-1`.

`FNR>1 && ++k%n!=0{next}` : increment `k` with each line after first/header line 
and if the remainder with `n` doesn't give zero that means it's not the nth record and don't print it. Else It's `nth` and print it.

Below version to help you understand better :

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{print; next;}  a!=$1{a=$1; n=$3; k=0; print; next} ++k%n==0{print}' f1
Id  TagNo   Nth
a   A-A-3   3
a   A-A-2   3
b   B-B-5   4
```

`FNR==1{print; next;}`:  Simply print header and do nothing

`a!=$1{a=$1; n=$3; k=0; print; next}` : `a` is a variable that keeps track of the first field/column. If `a` is not initialized or the first column is different than the previous one then set `a`, `n` and `k=0`.

`++k%n==0{print}` : Keep incrementing `k` with each new record and if the remainder with `n` gives zero that means it's the nth record.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
df <- data.table(read.table(text = "Id  TagNo   Nth
a   A-A-3   3
a   A-A-1   3
a   A-A-5   3
a   A-A-2   3
a   AX-45   3
a   AX-33   3
b   B-B-5   4
b   B-B-4   4
b   B-B-3   4
b   BX-B2   4", header = T))

df <- df[, id := seq_len(.N), by = Id]
df[id %% Nth == 1 , 1:3, by = Id]

  Id TagNo Nth
1:  a A-A-3   3
2:  a A-A-2   3
3:  b B-B-5   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Python solution:

```
with open('YOURFILENAME', 'r') as f:
    i = 1
    print('Id  TagNo   Nth')
    for line in f.readlines():
        if not i:
            print(line, end='')
            i = int(line.split()[-1])
        i -= 1
```

You can change the print() to write() or any other functions you want.
Since the header is fixed, I didn't include it in my code.

Update: Print the header separately.

Comment: Thank you; but your solution is incomplete; and it has an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Id,TagNo,Nth'`. What it means is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903967/invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-what-does-this-actually-mean). In other words, `int` doesn't know how to convert the argument passed via `line.split()[-1]`

Comment: @deepseefan Good to know. But I think the problem is you didn’t skip the first line since the last element in the header is “Nth” instead of a number. Cuz the header is fixed, I didn’t handle that in my code.